# Alternative to try/catch for checking if a function exists in javascript

Tags: javascript, try-catch

The following statement is used because the method in question (refreshPartyList()) may not always be defined.

```
try {
  parent.document.getElementById("myId").contentWindow.refreshPartyList(param1, param2);
}catch(e){}
```

Currently using the above approach and it is working fine, but is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var e = parent.document.getElementById("myId").contentWindow;
if(e.refreshPartyList)
  e.refreshPartyList(param1, param2);
```

Comment: This seems straightforward to me.  Done properly, the try/catch can sometimes be less code and simpler to read, but this straightforward `if` statement should work fine if you don't want try/catch.

Comment: @jfriend00 are you trying to justify a try/catch because it's "less code" even though a) there's an empty catch block and b) it's a massive performance overhead?

Comment: @Raynos - This example is so simple, I wouldn't use try/catch, but I've seen code that was multiple pages and littered with 50 `if` statements that could have been surrounded by one single try/catch and no `if` statements.  In general try/catch is underutilized in JS programming.  It's not for every situation, but there are many good situations for it where few people use it.  That's all I was trying to point out.

Comment: @jfriend00 and your suggesting one big try/catch to replace 50 if statements is _ever_ a good idea?

Comment: @Raynos - yes a single try/catch can be very useful instead of having to test a whole bunch of conditions if your function is essentially go/no-go (e.g. go if you can, otherwise just skip the function execution).  Why would that be bad?

Comment: @jfriend00 ... Performance reasons aside, exceptions are _exceptional_. One should not abuse `try/catch` and one should definitely not have an empty catch statement. You just _swallowed_ every single error thrown in that entire block. It just reeks of epicly bad code.

Comment: @Raynos - I'm not going to argue this with you as I think you're taking a theoretical position that is way too broad to be tenable.  In my opinion, exception handlers are very useful in many circumstances and, yes, sometimes I use empty `catch(e) {}` blocks in production (I often output something in debugging mode so I can evaluate whether this is an expected condition or not).  catch blocks don't swallow errors, they catch them.  Sometimes the desired handling of the error is to skip on to the next piece of code (in which case an empty catch block is perfectly appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the method exists with a simple if:

```
   if (parent.document.getElementById("myId").contentWindow.refreshPartyList) {
       parent.document.getElementById("myId").contentWindow.refreshPartyList(param1, param2);
   }
```

Or better still, with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/) (because the `if` does not guarantee it is a function):

```
   if (jQuery.type(parent.document.getElementById("myId").contentWindow.refreshPartyList) == 'function') {
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, then its available, and x.method might not be a callable function. (and a down vote for that - wow!)

Comment: the main downvote is for using `jQuery.type` instead of `typeof`. It's simply epic library abuse.

Comment: +1 for noting that the other methods result in a failure if `refreshPartyList` isn't a function. There, now your negative vote is offset.

Comment: @Raynos: `typeof` isn't exactly reliable for telling what is a function. Though you may be referring to having it return `'undefined'` if a variable doesn't exist, which is reliable.

Comment: @alex sorry what, Your going to have to back up what you mean "not reliable". typeof is rock solid for function identification.

Comment: @Raynos: `typeof /\d/` in older WebKits is `'function'`. [Source](http://perfectionkills.com/2009/11/#typeof-new-regexp-function). Also, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette). I've seen you be inpolite to users here numerous times.

Comment: @alex and it's also callable. That's because regular expressions in older webkits are also functions.

Comment: @Raynos - typeof is only reliable for native functions, it is absolutely **not** reliable for host methods. And yes, jQuery's type checking is equivalent to typeof so useless for host objects.

Comment: @RobG that's an aside, it's a true point though. I presume its only unreliable on IE<9

Comment: @Raynow - there is nothing in any W3C standard or specification that says host object must conform to ECMA-262 in any respect, so it does not seem sensible to expect that they will (and it is known that they don't).

Answer (score 1):

```
var win = parent.document.getElementById("myId").contentWindow;
win.refreshPartyList && win.refreshPartyList(param1, param2);
```

Use `x.method && x.method(...)` to check whether the method exists.

Comment: I like the shorter syntax which would allow just two lines, but using short-circuit evaluation has always seemed just a tiny bit more obscure. :)